# Angular 1 uiRouter how to get full path with url query?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to get the url path with it's current url queries using uiRouter.

What I want to achieve is something similar to:
`window.location.pathname + window.location.search`

How would one achieve this via uiRouter?

I've tried console logging `$location` but the `path` doesn't bring the url query, just the path.

Comment: `$location.url()`

Answer (score 0):

you can try with below code to get full url with all segments.

```
 // given URL http://yoururl.com/#/some/path?val1=bar&val2=xoxo
    var absUrl = $location.absUrl();
 // "http://yoururl.com/#/some/path?val1=bar&val2=xoxo"
```

Thanks